# Where to put 'already' in present continous

Tags: british-english, present-continuous

Can you help me where to put '**already**' in an English sentence which is **in present continuous**? Generally.

For example in this sentence.

> We are starting at 6 o'clock in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Starting" is not a good verb to use with "already".  [In most cases you would say something has "already *started*" rather than "already *starting*".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=already+started%2C+already+starting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

> We already started at 6 AM this morning.

However you may use "already" with verbs that indicate continuous (or ongoing) action:

> We are already walking to the theater.
>
> Hurry over, they are already serving dinner.
>
> She is already learning the trumpet, but now she wants to learn the trombone as well.

Comment: Thank you. What about the verb **to begin** (began)?

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič More or less the same as "to start".  "We already began practicing before the sun came up."